# one Textwatcher for two Edittexts - android

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I have two Edittexts, and when the first Edittext changes, set the text output for the second Edittext.  and when the second Edittext changes, set the text output for the first Edittext.   How do I set them up?

thanks

```
 inputValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextValue);
 ResultView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TextViewResult);
 inputValue.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);                    
 ResultView.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

 public TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    private View view;

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {

    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {



     }
    }
};
```

Comment: Create a class that implements TextWatcher. This class should have a Constructor that takes as paramter an EditText. Create two different instance of this class. One for the first EditText and pass as paramter the second one

Comment: Hey did my solution below work?

Answer (score 1):

create 2 textwatchers e.g am and am2

```
TextWatcher am,am2;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.YOUR_XML);


    am = new TextWatcher(){
           public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
           }
           public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
           }
           public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

              inputValue.addTextChangedListener(this);

               ResultView.setText("");
           }
    };

    am2 = new TextWatcher(){
           public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {       
           }
           public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
           }
           public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                  ResultView.addTextChangedListener(this);

                   inputValue.setText("");
           }
     };

    inputValue.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener(){
                public void onFocusChange (View v, boolean hasFocus){
                inputValue.removeTextChangedListener(am);
                ResultView.removeTextChangedListener(am2);
                setOnTextChangedListener(hasFocus);
                }
       }); 

    }
```

Comment: Can you please tell what is 'edit' in above code and where to declare it?